# Binomial Coefficient: Why are we dividing instead of subtracting?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Disclaimer: I'm new to combinations and permutations.

Observation: If it's $\frac {permutations} {ways}$, each way is $\frac {permutations} {ways}$ permutations.

Problem: Given $n \choose k$, I more or less intuitively understand the binomial coefficient: $\frac {n!} {k! (n-k)!}$ thanks to Khan Academy's [intuition video on Combination formula](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob-comb/combinations/v/combination-formula). But, why are we dividing ways instead of subtracting the "repeats" (i.e., the ways to arrange k that were *already* counted as combinations)?

Question: Rephrasing my question: how could you calculate what to subtract without already knowing the answer to $n \choose k$? For example, in $${4 \choose 3}=4$$ you know that $4! = 24$, so $$24-x=4$$ $$x=20$$ where x represents "repeats." But I had to know the answer was 4 to calculate x. Simply put then, is it possible to calculate 20 without knowing 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to work with units is a good start.

You divide rather than subtract because the number of repeats *per* permutation is constant. So for three element subsets of a $10$ element set there are $10\times 9 \times 8$ ways to choose the three elements in order, but that finds each subset $3!$ times.

To subtract instead of dividing  you'd have to know how many subsets there were (and multiply that by $3!$) but finding the number of sets is the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

To give a conceptual answer: It's ugly to look at **X**'s in a particular order, going one by one, saying "***this*** *is the first one with this property, any after this one I'll disregard*" and then counting how many "firsts" you got. In contrast, it's simple and clean to treat all **X**'s on an equal footing without distinguishing any particular ones, form groups of the **X**'s according to whether they have some property, and then count the groups.

(Here, **X**'s are arrangements of $k$ out of $n$ objects.)